# How to compare SQL files and Packages in Python and return True or False?

Tags: python, sql, difflib

So, I've tried using Differ from difflib and also filecmp. Here's what I've done so far:

```
def comparesqlpkg(pkg1Name, pkg2Name):
    d = Differ()
    if d.compare(open(pkg1Name, 'r').readlines(), open(pkg2Name, 'r').readlines()):
    #if filecmp.cmp(pkg1Name, pkg2Name):
        print("SAME content.")
        return True
    else:
        print("DIFFERENT content.")
        return False
```

I want the code to check the two files and see if they are the same and return True/False. The thing is that some reformatting can occur at Oracle's end that would modify the formatting of the second file. I need it to be in such a way that it would ignore that so that both scripts that run the same code (different tab spaces,etc) would still produce the same result.

Sample SQL1 (local repo):

```
function fn_get_number(
 in_src_amt in varchar2)
RETURN NUMBER;
```

Sample SQL2 (reformatted by ORACLE db):

```
FUNCTION FN_GET_NUMBER
(
     IN_SCR_AMT        IN        VARCHAR2
)
RETURN NUMBER;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all spaces and newlines, convert to lower case, and compare.

```
def transform(s):
    return s.replace(' ','').replace('\n','').lower()
...
if transform(open(pkg1name,'r').read()) == transform(open(pkg2name,'r').read()):
```